# BizTalk FlatFile Schema multiple repeating records

Tags: schema, biztalk, flat-file

I have a flat file and I need to create a schema so I can convert that flat file into XML and bring it to BizTalk.

I have used flat file schema wizard to create a schema but it is not working. I've modified it manually still not working. I will explain what is not working.

```
Flat File structure:
File header
Batch header
Detail (repeating records)
Address (repeating records)
Trailer
END
```

After creating the schema I'm trying to validate it and I'm getting error at this point.
Detail and Address are the body and they are repeatable. 
My issue is that after it reads the line "DET" it is suppose to read the "ADD". However it is looking for "DET" again.

> Error description:
>   error BEC2004: Unexpected data found while looking for:
>   'DET'
>   The current definition being parsed is RefundsRoot. The stream offset where the error occured is 799. The line number where the error occured is 4. The column where the error occured is 0.

Here is the sample

```
FDR06281339CREDIT REFUND CHECKS                                AC
HDR9008100000000000100006428
DET900810000000636992103500048763699210350004876369921035000487STMT, TEST 5                01TEST 5 STMT                                         6902 PINE ST                                        OMAHA             NE68106-2855                  0000000000+0000000000500000                 00FINUT A    +00000000000004900                         FHSC999999          +0000000000500     EN          0099000000000                            +0000000000000+000000000000000000+0000000000000+000000000000000000+0000000000000+0000000000000000000000000000+00009999999999999+00009999999999999+00000000000000000+00000000000000000+999999999999999+99999999999999900000000000+9999999999999990000000000000009900
ADDF                                                                                                                                                      6902 PINE ST                                                                                                                                                                                                      OMAHA                    NE                         68106-2855USA
TRL90081000000000001000000020000000000000642800000000000004900000000000000000000
END000000100000000200000000000000000000004900000000000000000000
```

Here is the schema (due to character limits I've only included related section)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Fingerhut.BizTalk.Schemas.FSIn_Refunds" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Fingerhut.BizTalk.Schemas.FSIn_Refunds" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char="0x0A 0x0D" pad_char_type="hex" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="true" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="true" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="RefundsRoot" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="RefundsRoot">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
              <xs:complexType name="Detail">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
          <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
        </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:element name="DETL-HDR" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="3" sequence_number="1" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-SYSTEM" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="4" sequence_number="2" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-PRIN-BANK" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="4" sequence_number="3" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-AGENT-BANK" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="4" sequence_number="4" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-ACCOUNT-NUMBER" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="16" sequence_number="5" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-PRMR-PI-ID" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="16" sequence_number="6" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-ENTR-ID" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="16" sequence_number="7" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-PI-NM" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="26" sequence_number="8" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-FILLER" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="2" sequence_number="9" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-PI-ROLE-CD" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="2" sequence_number="10" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-PRIMARY-NAME" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="26" sequence_number="11" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-SECONDARY-NAME" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="26" sequence_number="12" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-ADDRESS-LINE-1" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="26" sequence_number="13" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-ADDRESS-LINE-2" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="26" sequence_number="14" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-CITY" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="18" sequence_number="15" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-STATE" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="2" sequence_number="16" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-POST-CODE" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="10" sequence_number="17" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-REF-NUM" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="18" sequence_number="18" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-CHK-STARTING-NUM" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="5" sequence_number="19" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-NUMBER-OF-CKS" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="4" sequence_number="20" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-DUALITY-FLAG" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="1" sequence_number="21" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-CREDIT-LIMIT" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="14" sequence_number="22" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-NUMBER-OF-PLASTICS" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="3" sequence_number="23" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DETL-CHECKING-ACCOUNT-NUM" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="17" sequence_number="24" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Address">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
          <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
        </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-EXPN-ADDR-RCRD-HEDR-ID" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="3" sequence_number="1" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-PRMR-CUST-ADDR-FRMT-CD" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="1" sequence_number="2" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-ATTN-LINE-TX" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="50" sequence_number="3" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-CMPN-NM" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="50" sequence_number="4" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-HOUS-NR" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="10" sequence_number="5" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-STRT-NM" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="40" sequence_number="6" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-CNTN-ADDR-LINE-1-TX" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="50" sequence_number="7" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-CNTN-ADDR-LINE-2-TX" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="50" sequence_number="8" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-CNTN-ADDR-LINE-3-TX" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="50" sequence_number="9" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-CNTN-ADDR-LINE-4-TX" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="50" sequence_number="10" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-PO-BOX-TX" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="10" sequence_number="11" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-CITY-NM" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="25" sequence_number="12" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-ST-CD" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="2" sequence_number="13" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-SBDV-TX" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="25" sequence_number="14" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-PSTL-CD" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="10" sequence_number="15" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-CTRY-CD" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="3" sequence_number="16" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ADDR-FILLER" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="17" justification="left" pos_length="271" pos_offset="0" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following schema works (you of cause need to change my string elements to the correct positional record).

What you have to do is:

1. Add a record after the flat file wizard.
2. Put the record after your FDR element.
3. Add your repeating records DEC ADD to this new records as child elements.
4. Set the record to unbound
5. Set Child order Infix
6. Child delimiter type to Hex
7. Child delimiter to 0x0D 0x0A

This gives you the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://FlatFileSchema4" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://FlatFileSchema4" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
            <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="Root" />
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="postfix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="FDR">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                            <b:recordInfo structure="positional" tag_name="FDR" tag_offset="0" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:appinfo>
                                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                                </xs:appinfo>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:element name="FDR" type="xs:string">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="35" sequence_number="1" />
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                </xs:annotation>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="HDR">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                            <b:recordInfo structure="positional" tag_name="HDR" tag_offset="0" sequence_number="2" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:appinfo>
                                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                                </xs:appinfo>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:element name="HDR" type="xs:string">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="29" sequence_number="1" />
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                </xs:annotation>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="RR">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                            <recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="3" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" child_order="infix" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:appinfo>
                                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                                </xs:appinfo>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:element name="DET">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <b:recordInfo structure="positional" tag_name="DET" tag_offset="0" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" />
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                </xs:annotation>
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:appinfo>
                                                <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                                            </xs:appinfo>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:element name="DET" type="xs:string">
                                            <xs:annotation>
                                                <xs:appinfo>
                                                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="482" sequence_number="1" />
                                                </xs:appinfo>
                                            </xs:annotation>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="ADD">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <b:recordInfo structure="positional" tag_name="ADD" tag_offset="0" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="2" />
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                </xs:annotation>
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:appinfo>
                                                <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                                            </xs:appinfo>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:element name="ADD" type="xs:string">
                                            <xs:annotation>
                                                <xs:appinfo>
                                                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="41" sequence_number="1" />
                                                </xs:appinfo>
                                            </xs:annotation>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="TRL">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                            <b:recordInfo structure="positional" tag_name="TRL" tag_offset="0" sequence_number="4" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:appinfo>
                                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                                </xs:appinfo>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:element name="TRL" type="xs:string">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="81" sequence_number="1" />
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                </xs:annotation>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="END">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                            <b:recordInfo structure="positional" tag_name="END" tag_offset="0" sequence_number="5" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:appinfo>
                                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                                </xs:appinfo>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:element name="END" type="xs:string">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="63" sequence_number="1" />
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                </xs:annotation>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

With test file:

```
FDR06281339CREDIT REFUND CHECKS AC 
HDR9008100000000000100006428 
DET900810000000636992103500048763699210350004876369921035000487STMT, TEST 5 01TEST 5 STMT 6902 PINE ST OMAHA NE68106-2855 0000000000+0000000000500000 00FINUT A +00000000000004900 FHSC999999 +0000000000500 EN 0099000000000 +0000000000000+000000000000000000+0000000000000+000000000000000000+0000000000000+0000000000000000000000000000+00009999999999999+00009999999999999+00000000000000000+00000000000000000+999999999999999+99999999999999900000000000+9999999999999990000000000000009900 
ADDF 6902 PINE ST OMAHA NE 68106-2855USA 
DET900810000000636992103500048763699210350004876369921035000487STMT, TEST 5 01TEST 5 STMT 6902 PINE ST OMAHA NE68106-2855 0000000000+0000000000500000 00FINUT A +00000000000004900 FHSC999999 +0000000000500 EN 0099000000000 +0000000000000+000000000000000000+0000000000000+000000000000000000+0000000000000+0000000000000000000000000000+00009999999999999+00009999999999999+00000000000000000+00000000000000000+999999999999999+99999999999999900000000000+9999999999999990000000000000009900 
ADDF 6902 PINE ST OMAHA NE 68106-2855USA 
TRL90081000000000001000000020000000000000642800000000000004900000000000000000000 
END000000100000000200000000000000000000004900000000000000000000
```

And output:

```
  <Root xmlns="http://FlatFileSchema4">
        <FDR xmlns="">
            <FDR>FDR06281339CREDIT REFUND CHECKS AC</FDR>
        </FDR>
        <HDR xmlns="">
            <HDR>HDR9008100000000000100006428</HDR>
        </HDR>
        <RR xmlns="">
            <DET>
                <DET>DET900810000000636992103500048763699210350004876369921035000487STMT, TEST 5 01TEST 5 STMT 6902 PINE ST OMAHA NE68106-2855 0000000000+0000000000500000 00FINUT A +00000000000004900 FHSC999999 +0000000000500 EN 0099000000000 +0000000000000+000000000000000000+0000000000000+000000000000000000+0000000000000+0000000000000000000000000000+00009999999999999+00009999999999999+00000000000000000+00000000000000000+999999999999999+99999999999999900000000000+9999999999999990000000000000009900</DET>
            </DET>
            <ADD>
                <ADD>ADDF 6902 PINE ST OMAHA NE 68106-2855USA</ADD>
            </ADD>
        </RR>
        <RR xmlns="">
            <DET>
                <DET>DET900810000000636992103500048763699210350004876369921035000487STMT, TEST 5 01TEST 5 STMT 6902 PINE ST OMAHA NE68106-2855 0000000000+0000000000500000 00FINUT A +00000000000004900 FHSC999999 +0000000000500 EN 0099000000000 +0000000000000+000000000000000000+0000000000000+000000000000000000+0000000000000+0000000000000000000000000000+00009999999999999+00009999999999999+00000000000000000+00000000000000000+999999999999999+99999999999999900000000000+9999999999999990000000000000009900</DET>
            </DET>
            <ADD>
                <ADD>ADDF 6902 PINE ST OMAHA NE 68106-2855USA</ADD>
            </ADD>
        </RR>
        <TRL xmlns="">
            <TRL>TRL90081000000000001000000020000000000000642800000000000004900000000000000000000</TRL>
        </TRL>
        <END xmlns="">
            <END>END000000100000000200000000000000000000004900000000000000000000</END>
        </END>
    </Root>
```

I have updated the schema to also include the extra records that your testfile now have. And it works for me.

Comment: Due to character limits I was unable add multiple. I can put it here and you can add it to the above file. DET900810000000636992100000616263699210000061626369921000006162THOMPSON,ICILDA             01ICILDA THOMPSON                                     2122 WARREN ST                                      EVANSTON          IL60202-1954                  0000000000+0000000000900000                 00FINUT A    000000000000029.10       02000             F249999999          +0000000000900  029EN          024.90000.00000                            +00000000000.00+00099999999999900.0000.00000.00024.900

Comment: Here is the 2nd line. You can copy and repeat them multiple times. ADDF                                                                                                                                                      2122 WARREN ST                                                                                                                                                                                                    EVANSTON                 IL                         60202-1954USA

Comment: 1- Yes, it is positional file with line breaks (CRLF) at the end of each line. 2- Due to character limit I have omit some data that is why it doesn't look the same. 3- they always be in order (DET ADD, DET ADD, DET ADD) Meaning every DET should have ADD. Does this make sense. The issue is when it is reading line 4 it is expecting tag identifier DET instead of ADD. This is where it is failing and I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: I've tried but I'm getting different error. Default Pad Character and Default Child Delimiter are set to 0x0D 0x0A but I'm still getting this error BEC2004: Unexpected end of stream while looking for:
'\r\n'
The current definition being parsed is DET. The stream offset where the error occured is 1379. The line number where the error occured is 8. The column where the error occured is 0.

Comment: forgot to mention that "Allow Early Termination" is set to True.

Comment: I will try your schema and test file. I reviewed the test file it looks good. File ends at line 6 and line 7 is blank. I'm really confused why the error is talking about line 8. Here is the file structure Line 1 - FDR, Line 2 - HDR, Line 3 - DET, Line 4 - ADD, Line 5 - TRL, Line 6 - END

Comment: Thanks for your help it worked. However, it is not working when some of the data is missing from the column (when column ended at 600 instead of 700 characters).